# Android WebView loading the URL in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, url, android-activity, paypal, webview

I am trying to load a paypal url in web view and its loading in Nexus4 emulator, when I am trying to run the app in my device (ASUS Zenfone 5) the url is not loading and it showing like

> `Webpage not available`

I tried some solution for that like `setting the user agent`, `sslerror exceptions` but nothing worked in my case.

The below code is what I tried yet.

```
String PaypalURl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=xxxxxxxxxx";
wv_paypalView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view_paypal);
        wv_paypalView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv_paypalView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv_paypalView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv_paypalView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
//        wv_paypalView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");             
        wv_paypalView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; ASUS_T00J Build/KVT49L) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.78 Mobile");
        wv_paypalView.setWebViewClient(
                new SSLTolerentWebViewClient()
        );  
wv_paypalView.loadUrl(PaypalURl);
```

**SSLTolerentWebViewClient Class**

```
 private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }

    }
```

How I can resolve this,Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

PS: I checked the webview with another https url and its working fine but not for the above url .

Comment: Could be encoding issue. Debug  and check the url in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and see if it is proper.

Comment: @AbhishekV , OK. Thanks for the info dude. let me check.

Comment: Some checks that you've of course already done, just to be sure. You have an internet connection on your phone? The userAgent you set is available? Does the webview work with antoher url?

Comment: @Aster ,Thanks for the suggetions. I am sure about internet connection and internet permission.  Can you please explain me what you mean by "The userAgent you set is available?", I got the user agent from http://user-agents.me/device/asus-zenfone-5. Rather than this where i can get the user agent for my phone.

Comment: @Aster . FYI: I checked with another https url and its working fine.